# When treeselect has null value it won't show

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I need a `TreeNode` in `antd` [`TreeSelect`](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/), to have a value `null`.
But when it has a value `null`, it doesn't show it in the `TreeSelect`

```
<Tree.TreeNode value={null} title="Head menu"/>
```

How do i fix this?

New->

```
getSubSelectTree = (topMenuItem: TopMenuItem) => {
    if (topMenuItem.subMenu.length > 0) {
        let subMenuTreeNodes = [];
        for (let x = 0; x < topMenuItem.subMenu.length; x++) {
            subMenuTreeNodes.push(this.getSubSelectTree(topMenuItem.subMenu[x]));
        }
        return <Tree.TreeNode key={topMenuItem.id.toString()} title={topMenuItem.name}
                              value={topMenuItem.id}>{subMenuTreeNodes}</Tree.TreeNode>
    }
    return <Tree.TreeNode key={topMenuItem.id.toString()} title={topMenuItem.name} value={topMenuItem.id}
    />;
};

getSelectTree = () => {
    if (this.props.menuState.topMenu !== null) {
        if (!this.props.menuState.topMenu.loading) {
            let treeNodes = [];
            for (let x = 0; x < this.props.menuState.topMenu.menuItems.length; x++) {
                treeNodes.push(this.getSubSelectTree(this.props.menuState.topMenu.menuItems[x]));
            }
            return <TreeSelect
                placeholder="Selecteer onder welk menu item het moet komen."
                allowClear
            >
                <Tree.TreeNode value={"" + null} title={"Head menu"}/>
                {treeNodes}
            </TreeSelect>;
        }
    }
    return <></>;
};
```

This is my code right now. The only thing i want is to have a extra TreeNode that says that its a head menu and i wont have a parent when creating. And under water its null

Comment: Are you sure `TreeNode` has `prop` `value`? I don't think so. https://ant.design/components/tree/#TreeNode-props .

Comment: https://ant.design/components/tree-select/#TreeNode-props

Answer (score 0):

To show simply the title you can remove the value and use it like as shown below

```
 <Tree>
    <Tree.TreeNode title={"Head Menu"}></Tree.TreeNode>
 </Tree>
```

Comment: Then still it doesn't show the "Head Menu" in the main <TreeSelect> component

Comment: can you just create a codesandbox so it will be helpful to check. I have tried the above snippet in local it was showing

Answer (score 0):

Your question reads [`TreeSelect`](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/), but your code is about [`Tree`](https://ant.design/components/tree/). Don't be confused.

In case of `TreeSelect`, prop `value` needs to be an `object` or `string` or `false`, rather than `null` or `undefined`. It must be unique for each `TreeNode`.Check out [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-59154830-tree-select?file=index.js), let me know

```
render() {
    return (
      <TreeSelect
        showSearch
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        value={this.state.value}
        dropdownStyle={{ maxHeight: 400, overflow: "auto" }}
        placeholder="Please select"
        allowClear
        treeDefaultExpandAll
        onChange={this.onChange}
      >
        <TreeNode value="parent 1" title="parent 1" key="0-1">
          <TreeNode value="parent 1-0" title="parent 1-0" key="0-1-1">
            <TreeNode value={"" + undefined} title="my leaf" key="random" />
            <TreeNode value={"" + null} title="your leaf" key="random1" />
          </TreeNode>
          <TreeNode value="parent 1-1" title="parent 1-1" key="random2">
            <TreeNode
              value={false}
              title={<b style={{ color: "#08c" }}>sss</b>}
              key="random3"
            />
          </TreeNode>
        </TreeNode>
      </TreeSelect>
    );
  }
```

Comment: The <TreeNode> that I want to select means it doesn't have a parent. I'm building a cms but it needs to be proof for dumb people. So i need a Select with text that it will be a Head menu and doesn't have a parent that way

Comment: Could you create a code sandbox or edit your post and add details to it?

Comment: Editted my post